# Unable to fetch image from urn in the linkedln api

Tags: api, linkedin-api

After fetching the posts from linkedln api i am getting the images in the form of urn:li:image:C5622AQGiK47kSf7WQg .Let me know is there any way that i can fetch the image in the form of url so that i can display it in my mobile.

```
{
  "isReshareDisabledByAuthor": false,
  "createdAt": 1674689143221,
  "lifecycleState": "PUBLISHED",
  "lastModifiedAt": 1674689143272,
  "visibility": "PUBLIC",
  "publishedAt": 1674689143221,
  "author": "urn:li:organization:10309806",
  "id": "urn:li:share:7024155371388751872",
  "distribution": {
    "feedDistribution": "MAIN_FEED",
    "thirdPartyDistributionChannels": []
  },
  "content": {
    "media": {
      "id": "urn:li:image:C5622AQGiK47kSf7WQg"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get image url by [urn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/images-api?view=li-lms-2023-05&tabs=curl#get-a-single-image) and use downloadUrl for preview image

```
{
  "downloadUrl": "https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/sync/D4D27AQGEgNz4EivtUg/articleshare-shrink_1280_800/0/1685978305837?e=1687168800&v=beta&t=TccyGoswQ_pPI1ewAUrhvPMsEgDYQsexOqoJf1N3UOI",
  "owner": "urn:li:article:8195701583010840995",
  "id": "urn:li:image:D4D27AQGEgNz4EivtUg",
  "downloadUrlExpiresAt": 1687168800000,
  "status": "AVAILABLE"
}
```